# jQuery: Selecting the text when p contains a listpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some comments in a guestbook. p containins '(In [ 'sometimes. The '(In [' sometimes contains a list.

```
 <div class="comment searchable">
 <p>
(In <a class="changeset" href="/../" sets mynumber">[Phonebook]</a>)
</p>
<ul><li><tt>Name</tt>, <tt>Number</tt> 
</li></ul>

<p>is <a class="is new entry" href="/../mynumber">new entry</a>
</p>
 </div>
```

This is how I get all '(In' 's and some text in the same line. I insert them in a 'box' after a div.

```
    $("<div id='createDiv' style='border:1px outset #999966;padding:1em;margin-top:1em'></div>").insertAfter("#changelog");
    $("#createDiv").append($("p:contains('In [')").clone());
```

But how do I select and insert the whole text when the comments also contains a listpoint?

I'm using jQapi as a reference which is very useful. I was looking for sth like:
p:contains('li').

Thank you in advance for any hint.

**Edit:** What should come out:

(In [Phonebook])  Name, Number is new entry.

Now it is:
(In [Phonebook])

Comment: Given the example markup in the question, what text do you *want* to come out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is replacing:

```
$("p:contains('In [')").clone()
```

With:

```
$("p:contains('In [')").closest("div").clone()
//or...
$("div.comment:contains('In [')").clone()
```

Or if you just want the children:

```
$("p:contains('In [')").closest("div").children().clone()
//or...
$("div.comment:contains('In [')").children().clone()
```

You have a few options here, depending on what you want your edit to look like.  If you just cared about the text for example, this would suffice:

```
$("div.comment:contains('In [')").text()
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times. It's working fine now. I've chosen option number one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are lookin for [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: ($("p:contains('In ['),p:has(li)").clone()).appendTo($("#createDiv")); would it be then, I guess. But how do I select the 'text' from 'li' ?

Answer (score 0):

is this:

> (In [Phonebook]) Name, Number is new entry

what you wanted?

```
$("div p:contains('In [')").parent().text()
```